# Why does returning a list from a function output the same twice?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to sum the even values of a Fibonacci sequence, however, when I do so I get the same output twice in a row:

```
[2, 8, 34, 2, 8, 34]
```

as opposed to just

```
[2, 8, 34]
```

Below is the code:

```
number_sequence = 10
list_of_numbers = []
sum_of_numbers = []

def fibb_sequence():
    # init variables
    current_term = 2
    previous_term = 1
    list_of_numbers.append(previous_term)
    list_of_numbers.append(current_term)

    for i in range(2, number_sequence):
        # the magic happens
        new_num = current_term + previous_term
        previous_term = current_term
        current_term = new_num
        list_of_numbers.append(new_num)

    return list_of_numbers

def sum_added_values():
    for i in fibb_sequence():
        # find all even values
        if (i % 2) == 0:

            sum_of_numbers.append(i)

    print(sum_of_numbers)


print(fibb_sequence())
sum_added_values()
```

Why is it repeating itself?

Comment: You are never clearing `list_of_numbers`, so it simply grows longer each time you call `fibb_sequence()`.  There's no reason for that to be a global variable, you could create a new list inside `fibb_sequence()` and simply return it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the global lists `list_of_numbers` and `sum_of_numbers`  inside `fibb_sequence()`, so every time this function is called, the values are appended to these lists.

Either stop using such global objects, or only call `fibb_sequence()` once. For example, remove the `print(fibb_sequence())` line. Also, as `fibb_sequnce()` is called from within `sum_added_values()`, each call to `sum_added_values()` will append the values once more. Here the call to `fibb_sequence()` has been extracted so that it only happens once:

```py
number_sequence = 10
list_of_numbers = []
sum_of_numbers = []

def fibb_sequence():
    # init variables
    current_term = 2
    previous_term = 1
    list_of_numbers.append(previous_term)
    list_of_numbers.append(current_term)

    for i in range(2, number_sequence):
        # the magic happens
        new_num = current_term + previous_term
        previous_term = current_term
        current_term = new_num
        list_of_numbers.append(new_num)

    return list_of_numbers

def sum_added_values():
    for i in result:
        # find all even values
        if (i % 2) == 0:

            sum_of_numbers.append(i)

    print(sum_of_numbers)


result = fibb_sequence()
print(result)
sum_added_values()
```